# copy and past of HTML codes in Python

Tags: html, wxpython

I am trying to get a HTML code when a user tries to do copy&paste from a web browser. Generally, if you do a copy&paste from a webbrowser to a text editor, only the texts are copied, not the HTML codes. But, if you do it to a MS word, you can see that the layout information is preserved.

I am using wxPython. Is it possible to get a HTML code in wxPython when a user tries copy&paste from a HTML file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the source code of a webpage ?

In python try this :

```
import urllib 
codeSrc = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.fr').read()
print(codeSrc.find('google'))
```

Comment: No. I would like to get the HTML source code on the part a user do a copy&paste.